# Lists with Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm learning rooPlog and having some trouble with lists.  I want to return a list of classes that are prerequisites for a specified class.  Here is what I have so far...

```
prereq(262, 221).
prereq(271, 262).
prereq(331, 271).

prerequisites(A, B) :- not(prereq(A, C)).
prerequisites(A, [C|B]) :- prereq(A, C), prerequisites(C, B).
```

It works, but appends junk onto the end.

```
?- prerequisites(331, A).
A = [271, 262, 221|_G327] ;
false.
```

Comment: Always be wary of the 'singleton variable' warning because this means something is wrong. If u don't use some variable in a particular clause, make it anonymous by replacing it with a ' _ ' "prerequisites(A, B) :- not(prereq(A, C))." would have triggered the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you mean

```
prerequisites(A, []) :- not(prereq(A, _)).
prerequisites(A, [C|B]) :- prereq(A, C), prerequisites(C, B).
```

You must be sure there are no cycles in your data for this to work...

Comment: When trying to determine if a class is a prereq for another, this solution only works for the immediate predecessor.  So, prereq(262, 221). works, but prereq(271, 221). does not.

Comment: `prereq` it's a fact. `prerequisites` we wrote build a list, then we need a memberchk to use it: try `?-prerequistes(262,X),memberchk(221,X).`

Comment: great.  I didn't know about memberchk.  Thanks!